# How are solar spectra simulators used and are they used to test photo-diodes and image sensors?

Tags: solar-cell, infrared, photodiode, solar-energy, image-sensor

For example here is link to a Xenon lamp solar spectra simulator [Xenon lamp AAA Class Solar Simulator](https://www.allreal3a.com/en/products_1.php?id=17).
[image]

Two spectra are shown in the plot given in the link, one for the AM1.5G reference an other of the solar spectra simulator itself. If one needs to test e.g. an image sensor or a photo-diode signal produced from sunlight in 800 – 1100 nm range what is the benefit of using a solar simulator, since spectra in that band (800 -1000 nm) does not resemble the sunlight spectra at all. Actually it looks like a complete mess after 700 nm, and far from a good fit to the real solar spectra or AM1.5G.

Since other solar simulators I have looked up have a similar spectrum I don’t understand how are they used ? Are they used for testing photo-diodes and image sensors, that is to simulate the signals produced by the certain sunlight spectral bands at all, or I am missing the purpose of solar simulators ?

Comment: The AM1.5G is the filter you put over the source.! Then 2% error more or less withAAA

Comment: Solar simulators are primarily used to test solar cells. I have never heard of someone testing a an image sensor with one (do you care how efficiently the image sensor can take pictures of the sun?), but there is no reason you could not use it for that purpose if for example you were studying sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

A solar simulator is use to approximate the spectrum of the sun but do so with some control. The biggest reason is if you wanted to simulate cells in all sun conditions, you would have to go to the equator, where the sun is brightest at ~1000W/m^2. A solar simulator allows you to vary the power and take the measurements you need (and you don't have to wait the course of a day either for the sun to dim you can control the lights, or worry about atmospheric conditions.)

When testing satellite solar panels, I used a solar simulator to simulate the power of the sun in space. This ensured that the panels were wired correctly and gave the appropriate output power before sending it up into space. You only need to approximate the spectrum of the sun and get the overall shape right.

I would think more accurate sources are used for photodiode/imagesensors like tunable or uniform light sources.

Answer (score 0):

Solar simulators tries to match the true solar spectrum, but of course it never will perfectly match.

The AM1.5G spectrum is a standard defined as the sunlight through 1.5 times the airmass ang G for Global which include the diffuse component of the light (vs direct). The spectrum vary over the day and weather condition but an arbitrary Standard had to be defined so that measurements can be comparable. Space application uses AM0 (0 times airmass).

There are some standards to evaluate the spectral match to AM1.5 and usually gives a rating A, B, C, A+, on the [IEC60904-9](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/28973)  this standard is defined in bands and was amended in 2020 to extend from 300 to 1200nm.

For a long time, solar simulator used [Xenon light source](https://eternalsunspire.com/product/5100slp-aaa-single-long-pulse-flasher/), as this source is close to natural sunlight. However, as you mentioned, Xenon source exhibit large peaks at around 800 to 1000nm. Those peaks increases drastically the uncertainty as spectrometers are not good to deal with them, they saturate and average yielding to large uncertainties which are difficult to asses.

Filters can be used to improve these peaks but only to some extent.

In our day, [LED solar simulator](https://avalon.solar/nexun) are becoming more prevalent as Leds are getting better and farther into the IR. They have a much better control of the light and allow to adjust the spectrum between AM1.5 and AM0 or different spectrum. They have much better spectral match, no peaks and better life time.

[image: led solar simulator spectrum]